# perform segue in viewDidLoad() without navigation controller in Swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, segue, viewdidload

I have three views (view 1 checks a server connection, view 2 shows the main content, view3 shows the support page) and I created them in the storyboard without coding. On starting my iOS app the view 1 shows a spinner while checking the server connection. If the connection check is passed then I want to go to view 2 and if it's failed then I want to go to view 3. The view 1 is only for the connection check and I don't want to go back to this view. So, I think I don't need a navigation controller, or?

In storyboard I connected all view with seques. In my view controller of view 1 I do this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let result:Bool = server.isServerAvailable(myURL)

    if (result == true) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("ConnectionCheckToMain", sender: self)
    }
    else {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("ConnectionCheckToSupport", sender: self)
    }
}
```

But this segue in the `viewDidLoad()` function doesn't work, but I don't know why. I've added a button on view to check it. I've implemented the same code like in `viewDidLoad()` and it works fine. On clicking the button the next view loads.

Is there any idea why the code doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code for navigation.

```
    let vc : UIViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ConnectionCheckToMain") as! UIViewController;
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thx, but now I get the following message: **Warning: Attempt to present <HM.ViewControllerMain: 0x7ff488e2ba50> on <HM.ViewController: 0x7ff48b00e260> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!**. Where's my mistake?

Comment: I solved the problem, I migrated the code to viewDidAppear().

Comment: I tried this solution but I get an error **AnyObject is not convertible to 'UIViewController' did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?** why?

Comment: 'Cause Swift moved to 1.2, and now you have to force the downcast with the "as" alias. So : as! (1.2) = as (1.1).

Answer (score 6):

This code solve for me (Swift 3) using "segue" (please replace "ConnectionCheckToMain" with your segue name.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ConnectionCheckToMain", sender: nil)
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i solved it with this code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in   
            let viewController:UIViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerClassId") as! ViewControllerClassName
            self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
```