# Show a View Controller Programmatically in Swift error

Tags: ios, swift

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100220/perform-segue-in-viewdidload-without-navigation-controller-in-swift) but I get an error **AnyObject is not convertible to 'UIViewController' did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?**

What am I doing wrong?

I call the following code in LoginViewController viewDidLoad, I check if the user has logged in yet if yes then I want to skip the login view and go directly to Latest Photos which is FirstViewController...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if(defaults.objectForKey("loggedIn") != nil){
        let vc : UIViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LatestPhotosView") as! UIViewController;
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: It's ok to add links to external resources, but it would be much better if you include in the question the code you're having problems with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Swift 1.2, you have to cast explicitly, change your `as` to `as!`.

This indicates to the programmer that the cast can fail. This decreases the probability of errors in your code.

**Edit:**

You have to call this in your `viewDidAppear:` method, as this will fail on your `viewDidLoad()` (Your view doesn't exist yet)

Comment: Ok, now i get this at runtime **Warning: Attempt to present <your_app.FirstViewController: 0x7f87905726d0> on <your_app.LoginViewController: 0x7f879049a780> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!**

Comment: @TonyMorello I'll need some more code for that, edit your question to include more please. Where exactly do you call these methods?

Comment: @wrwim ok... If I have to call it on view did appear I could just trigger the segue that already exists... That work flawlessly except I don't want the login screen to show at all and when view appears it shows for like half a second... is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: If you want to skip a viewcontroller, you'll have to see where you load that view, and change the code there. If you want to skip the initial view controller, you'll have to load it manually from your `AppDelegate` like so: `window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds); window.rootViewController = ...; window.makeKeyAndVisible()`